# Combining paragraphs in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string:

> "He doesnt know me really, but theres a faint recognition there. I am the girl who brings the strawberries. The girl his daughter might have spoken of on occasion. The girl who five years ago stood huddled with her mother and
>
> sister, as he presented her, the oldest child, with a medal of valor. A medal for her father, vaporized in the mines. Does he remember that? What does it matter? he repeats gruffly. Let her come forward. Prim is screaming hysterically behind me. Shes wrapped her skinny arms around me like a vice."

How can I combine the two paragraphs to make it one large paragraph in Ruby?

Comment: Can you include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it? In particular you might find the [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html) documentation a good place to start

Comment: The answers contain many assumptions which is an indication for an unclear questions. What is your expected result? Will the split always occur between words? Should consecutive spaces (or tabs) be preserved? Why do you have those newlines in the first place? Where do they come from?

Comment: "How can I combine the two paragraphs to make it one large paragraph in Ruby?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

[`String#squeeze`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-squeeze) comes to the rescue:

```
input.squeeze($/)
```

Comment: That would replace the two newlines with a single newline. Not sure if that qualifies as "one large paragraph".

Comment: @Stefan I vote for it’s being markdown :) All other lines also end with `"\n"`.

Answer (score 2):

simple trick:

```
> string.split.join(" ")
```

another one:

```
> string.gsub!(/\s+/, ' ')
```

If you are using Rails, it provides **[String#squish](https://apidock.com/rails/String/squish)**

```
> string.squish
```

**Note:** Above all methods will remove extra spaces as well as line break and make it as single paragraph.

---

**Output:**

```
#=> "He doesnt know me really, but theres a faint recognition there. I am the girl who brings the strawberries. The girl his daughter might have spoken of on occasion. The girl who five years ago stood huddled with her mother and sister, as he presented her, the oldest child, with a medal of valor. A medal for her father, vaporized in the mines. Does he remember that? What does it matter? he repeats gruffly. Let her come forward. Prim is screaming hysterically behind me. Shes wrapped her skinny arms around me like a vice."
```

Comment: Simple and effective! If the string contained two or more adjacent whitespace chars, this would take all but one. That could be a problem if they were to be preserved or could be welcomed edit.

Comment: To preserve non-newline whitespace, you could use `string.split(/\n+/).join(' ')` or `string.gsub(/\n+/, ' ')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a text like

> before
>
> after

It means that there are two line breaks, something like this:

> before
>   BREAK
>
> BREAK
>
> after

So what you are trying to do is to replace two consecutive BREAKS with a space.

```
separated = "before\n\nafter"
combined = separated.gsub(/\n+/, " ")
```

Note that this does not have any context about your text structure or paragraphs.

Comment: OP might be on Windows, btw.

Comment: Good point. In any case, String#squeeze seems nicer.

Comment: Maybe `/\n+/` .

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes this might be even better. But I prefer the `squeeze` version from mudasobwa anyway. Did not know about squeeze.

Comment: The OP wants one large paragraph, so I think the line breaks should be replaced by a space: `separated.gsub(/\n+/, ' ')`.

Comment: @Stefan I think you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the break is on words, so that a space should be inserted between the two substrings (rather than, say, "...bicy\n\ncle..."). I also allow for the possibility of errant whitespace that should be removed.

```
def join_em(str)
  str.gsub(/(?:\s*\n){2,}/, ' ')
end

join_em("The cat is back.\n\nThe dog never left.")
  #=> "The cat is back. The dog never left."
join_em("The cat is back.  \n  \t \nThe dog never left.")
  #=> "The cat is back. The dog never left."
```